# Class designs with collections within them, with collections within those

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

In a continuation of my previous thread, I have found that a lot of my classes contain collections. Eg:

Engine - contains collection of pistons - piston - contains collection of xyz parts

Thus there is a hierarchy, as every component contains a collection of parts, which goes on and on.

This is a coding scenario I have not come across before. Constantly writing code like so:

```
class Part (Replace Part with apt name)
{
List<APart> parts ...
}
```

And then the same for APart, as that contains a collection of inner parts, is very tedious and therefore making me question whether this is the right way to code.

Is there a better way to write this sort of code? Anything like AOP etc I am open to (Though AOP is for cross-cutting concerns).

Comment: Side point: it's generally a good idea to adhere to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Collections of collections will tempt you to use multiple "dots." Resist!

Comment: How can you have been here for so long and not know these are not threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thought:

Your **Engine** class could contain a **PistonsManager** class, which manages the list of **Pistons**.  The **PistonsManager** could contain all of the logic to modify the list and shield the **Engine** class from having to think about **Pistons**.  By the same logic, your **PistonsManager** class could contain an **XYZPartsManager**.  This way you aren't programming list logic/management into your **Engine** logic, but have classes to do that.  It might make readability and make the logic flow nicely.

Comment: That has given me some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes coding is just tedious. However, there are often patterns that can be ferreted out of an implementation.

We have a situation similar to yours and discovered that there was an underlying recursive pattern. So we implemented a base class (call it Part) that itself can contain a List(Of Part). This can be as deep as needed.

The collection classes for specific class implementations are either generic collections of the specific type or implement an interface that allows us to get at specific data in the class (we had to implement the interface mechanism due to collection collisions in WCF).

The upshot is that you will probably have a lot of discrete Part inheritors, but your will will be a common way to instantiate, process, and traverse your elements with a common set of code.

**Update**

This is a severely contrived example, but one that should get you pointed in the right direction. In our application, we use a substantial amount of reflection and table-mapped class names in order to severely reduce the amount of repetitive code. This example reflects some of that behavior, but not all.

This example basically shows how you can have a generic part class which contains a recursive collection of parts which are indexed at the part type level. In other words, you will have Engine and Engine will have a collection of part collections indexed by part type. For example, Engine could have a collection of Pistons, a collection of hoses, etc. This design is obviously optional, but does make it somewhat easier to process.

Here are the main classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// The base part collection
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public class PartBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The key for the record, such as a recordid
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public virtual string CollectionKey {get; set;}

    public PartBase() : base()
    {
        m_cParts = new PartBaseCollections();
    }

    public virtual void InitializeFromDataRow(DataRow oRow)
    {
        // ToDo: Either implement generic column/datarow mapping through reflection or have each class override this method
    }

    private PartBaseCollections m_cParts;

    public PartBaseCollections Parts
    {
        get
        {
            return m_cParts;
        }
    }

    public PartBaseCollection GetParts(string sTableName)
    {
        if (this.Parts.Contains(sTableName))
        {
            return this.Parts(sTableName);
        }
        else
        {
            PartBaseCollection cParts = new PartBaseCollection(sTableName);
            this.Parts.Add(cParts);
            return cParts;
        }
    }

    public void AddParts(DataSet dsData)
    {

        foreach (DataTable oTable in dsData.Tables)
        {
            PartBaseCollection cParts = null;

            cParts = GetParts(oTable.TableName);

            cParts.AddRecordsFromTable(oTable);
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// A collection of PartBases keyed by a value, such as a table name (for example, Pistons)
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public class PartBaseCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, PartBase>
{

    public string CollectionKey {get; set;}
    public Type RecordType {get; set;}

    public PartBaseCollection(string TableName)
    {
        this.CollectionKey = TableName;
        // Assume that the TableName is a class in the current namespace
        RecordType = Type.GetType(this.GetType().Namespace + "." + TableName, false, true);
    }

    protected override string GetKeyForItem(PartBase item)
    {
        return item.CollectionKey;
    }

    public PartBase ManufactureRecord()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(this.RecordType);
    }

    public void AddRecordsFromTable(DataTable oTable)
    {

        foreach (DataRow oRow in oTable.Rows)
        {
            PartBase oPart = null;

            oPart = ManufactureRecord();
            oPart.InitializeFromDataRow(oRow);

            this.Add(oPart);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// All of the PartBaseCollection elements for a given PartBase
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public class PartBaseCollections : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, PartBaseCollection>
{

    protected override string GetKeyForItem(PartBaseCollection item)
    {
        return item.CollectionKey;
    }
}

public class Engine : PartBase
{

}

public class Piston : PartBase
{

}
```

And here is an example of creating the engine:

```
public void CreateEngine()
{

    DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
    DataTable oTable = new DataTable("Piston");

    dsData.Tables.Add(oTable);

    Engine oEngine = new Engine();

    oEngine.AddParts(dsData);
}
```

Comment: +1 for this as well.  I am always in favor of writing base classes!

Comment: @dotnetdev: I have added a (quite) contrived sample, but it is loosely based on what we currently do. Obviously, the actual implementation would need to reflect where you are getting your data from, but I would strongly recommend using reflection to move data into and out of the data structures. This has saved us tens of thousands of lines of otherwise repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the [composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) - consider looking at the [iterator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) and perhaps the [visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) as these usually go together.